# Universal Analyitics not tracking links that lead to popups

Tags: php, html, google-analytics, universal-analytics, event-tracking

I recently took over a small school website that was using some really convoluted analytics like a mix of UA and GA. So I stripped out all of the old analytics code, made a new account, and got everything running with UA. I'm only tracking link clicks so the code isn't too complicated. The issue I'm having is that links that lead to pop-ups don't send an event. When I watch the events in real time, links that lead to a new page send events perfectly, but links that just cause a pop-up don't. In the following snippet, the first link leads to another page and tracks, the second one generates a pop-up and doesn't track.

```html
<tr>
<td class="tableCenterBoxes">
 <a href="http://bit.ly/nutritionCalculator"
    target="_blank"
    onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'quickLinks', 'nutritionCalculator');">
  Nutrition Calculator
 </a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tableCenterBoxes">
 <a href="popups/ClubsAndOrganizationsFall2015.pdf"
    rel="clearbox[gallery=Resources,,width=650,,height=500,,title=Clubs and Organizations]"
    onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'quickLinks', 'clubsAndOrganizations');">
  Clubs and Organizations
 </a>
</td>
</tr>
```

I have no idea why this is happening so any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I ended up solving the issue by writing a simple javascript function called 'popup' which took in a url, title, category, and description. I then called the ga funtion and opened a clearbox popup from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Binding events

I see you use some clearbox plugin and this plugin is setted up by rel parameter. After page load, the script inside clearbox sets up event listeners onto each rel=clearbox param and sets its new behavior. It probably unbind previous onclick elements like your GA code. This is a problem and you can try to solve it in a few different ways.

## Quick and dirty

Set up this onclick listener by javascript after page loads with some delay - e.g. 1-2 seconds after onload. This just adds one more onclick event to existing configuration in your pop-up link with ClearBox.

## Correct approach

The Clearbox library has some callback functions.

**CB_AllowExtFunctLoad='on'** calls a function CB_ExternalFunctionLoad(); every time after a new content has loaded. In this function you can have you customized ga("send"...) calls...

**CB_AllowExtFunctPageLoad='on'**
calls a function named CB_ExternalFunctionPageLoad(); after your page has fully loaded. This is right place to set up your customized event listeners globally.

---

You can read more in clearbox documentation in section: Clearbox professional settings: http://kreaturamedia.com/clearbox/index_en.html

---

### Update

Event listeners setted by you can looks like (jQuery example):

### jQuery

```
<a href="popups/ClubsAndOrganizationsFall2015.pdf"
 rel="clearbox[gallery=Resources,,width=650,,height=500,,title=Clubs and Organizations]"
 data-description="clubsAndOrganizations">
    Clubs and Organizations
</a> 

<script>
var CB_AllowExtFunctPageLoad = function(){
 $(".tableCenterBoxes a").onclick(function(){
   var desc = $(this).attr("data-description");
   ga('send', 'event', 'quickLinks', desc);
 }); 
}
</script>
```

### Pure Javascript

```
<script>

function CB_ExternalFunctionLoad() { 

    var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("popup");

    var gaSetter = function() {
        var cat = this.getAttribute("data-category");
        var desc = this.getAttribute("data-description");
        ga('send', 'event', cat, desc);      
    };  

    for(var i=0;i<classname.length;i++){
       classname[i].addEventListener('click', gaSetter, false);
    }

}
</script>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I need to send unique information for each popup link. If I do it this way the same function is going to get called every time I click a popup right? I need so send google analyitics unique information for every popup. The more I look the more it looks like I might not be able to do this with clearbox. Any suggestions on a better way to do this?

Comment: Add some data-description parameter and then get this value by script into UA call. 

`<a href="popups/ClubsAndOrganizationsFall2015.pdf"    rel="clearbox[gallery=Resources,,width=650,,height=500,,title=Clubs and Organizations]"
    data-description="clubsAndOrganizations">
  Clubs and Organizations
 </a>`
If you will use, for instance jQuery then you set `$(".tableCenterBoxes a").onclick(function(){
var desc = $(this).attr("data-description");
ga('send', 'event', 'quickLinks', desc);

});`

Comment: Thank you I'm sure this code will get everything up and running. My issue now is I just don't know a lot about javascript and almost nothing about jquery. Does the jquery snippet need to be on every page that needs to run that function or just on my index page? And should it go before the </head> or </body> tag?

Comment: OK so I got something similar to this going but there is another problem. I'm using data-category and data-description in the CB_ExternalFunctionLoad() to pass the correct information to GA. But the data-description doesn't change when each link is clicked so it's just set to the first but of data it comes across. So if I click "clubs and organizations" GA tracks "clubsOrganizations" but if I click another popup like "who to know" GA still counts it as "clubsOrganizations".

Comment: <script>
   function CB_ExternalFunctionLoad()
   {
    var source = document.querySelector('#popup')
    var desc = source.dataset.description
    var cat = source.dataset.category
    ga('send', 'event', cat, desc);
   }
  </script>

Comment: <a href="popups/ClubsAndOrganizationsFall2015.pdf"
                       id="popup"
                       data-description="clubsAndOrganizations"
                       data-category="quickLinks"
                       rel="clearbox[gallery=Resources,,width=650,,height=500,,title=Clubs and Organizations]">
                        Clubs and Organizations
                    </a>

Comment: <a href="../popups/SOTWarchive.php" 
        id="popup"
                       data-description="whoToKnow"
                       data-category="quickLinks"
        rel="clearbox[gallery=Resources,,width=650,,height=500,,title=Student Of The Week Archive]">
      Who to Know
      <br>
      & Where to Go
     </a>

Comment: I see you use **id=popup** in more than one case, use **class=popup** instead. This may cause problem with all the time same value. ID have to be unique. Your callback in CB_ExternalFunctionLoad() is quite unhappy. It will works only with first ID popup in DOM. You need to attach evenbt listener click/onclick to each popup link in your webpage you want to track in this way.